# Firestore expressjs: how to get document where specific field exists and update the document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am using expressjs in the firebase cloud function trying to get a document where a specific field is the same as a  value that I already have,  So here is the  piece of code  :

```
const email =data.email (this is coming from stripe webhook ) 
  const document = db
        .collection('ConnectedAccounts')
        .where(`email`, '==', email)
        .get();
      console.log('document', document.data());
```

after getting this document I want to store a new field to it, I have tried the above code but failed, can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide the error that you got.

Comment: i haven't got any error, just didn't know how to access the doc and  do the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [execute a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) the response is a `QuerySnapshot` that can contain any number of documents. So you need to loop over the documents in that snapshot to get at the individual results:

```
const email =data.email (this is coming from stripe webhook ) 
const querySnapshot = await db
      .collection('ConnectedAccounts')
      .where(`email`, '==', email)
      .get();
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((docSnapshot) => {
  docSnapshot.ref.update({ ... your update here ...});
})
```

Comment: So the ref here is referencing the document we are getting from the query snapshot?  and i can add directly the field to it like querySnapshot.docs.forEach((docSnapshot) => {
  docSnapshot.ref.update({phone:phoneNumber});
})   right?